# metadata editing in bash linux for multimedia files(not images) in linux

Tags: linux, bash, metadata, exif, ogg

I've searched across stackoverflow, and I've been on google and also duckduckgo and no one seems to have a nice way for me to do this.

The only tool that seems to maybe have worked was Exiftool which only has the read ability for ogg files(which is what I'm using at the moment). I'd like some way to do this via the command line since the mp3s/oggs and their name is the metadata but the metadata is blank. I already know how to parse the file names in bash but I cannot find a way to put it back onto the files. I could manually do this kind of thing but it's hardly worth it since I'd have to do it manually.

Musicbrainz picard also doesn't tag them properly for some odd reason so that's why I'm having to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ID3` tags are MP3 specific. For Ogg Vorbis comment field specifications, see: [Field Names](http://www.xiph.org/vorbis/doc/v-comment.html)

`vorbiscomment` (package *vorbis-tools*) can modify and query  `ogg` tag info.
`mp3info` is one of many tools to work wirh `mp3` tags.

---

## .ogg

```
# Clear all info
printf ''| vorbiscomment -w  test.ogg
           vorbiscomment -l  test.ogg
# modify info
echo ========
printf 'TITLE=The Last Saskatchewan Pirate
ARTIST=Captain Tractor
ALBUM=East of Edson
DATE=2000-01-01
COMMENT=Just another TEST comment
DESCRIPTION=*** Hello ***
'|vorbiscomment -w  test.ogg
  vorbiscomment -l  test.ogg
echo ========
```

Output (.ogg)

```
========
TITLE=The Last Saskatchewan Pirate
ARTIST=Captain Tractor
ALBUM=East of Edson
DATE=2000-01-01
COMMENT=Just another TEST comment
DESCRIPTION=*** Hello ***
========
```

---

## mp3

```
# Delete the entire ID3 tag
mp3info -d test.mp3   
echo  ========
# modify info
mp3info -t "The Last Saskatchewan Pirate" \
        -a "Captain Tractor" \
        -l "East of Edson" \
        -g "Folk/Rock" \
        -y "2000" \
        -n "1" \
        -c "Just another TEST comment" \
        test.mp3
mp3info test.mp3
echo  ========
```

Output (.mp3)

```
========
File: test.mp3
Title:   The Last Saskatchewan Pirate   Track: 
Artist:  Captain Tractor
Album:   East of Edson                  Year:  2000
Comment: Just another TEST comment      Genre: Folk/Rock [81]

========
```